# $X_\alpha$ locally compact and all but a finite number of factors are compact $ \implies\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$ is locally compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, products

How can I prove that if $X_\alpha$ are locally compact and all but a finite number of factors are compact then $\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$ is locally compact?

What needs to be proved is

the existence of $K\subset \prod X_\alpha$ where $K$ is compact and $x\in int(K),x\in\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$.

As each $X_\alpha$ is locally compact, then we have that $\exists K_\alpha\subset X_\alpha$ where $K_\alpha$ are compact sets and $y_\alpha\in int(K_\alpha)$, for all $y_\alpha \in X_\alpha$ .

We also have that a finite number of $X_\alpha$ are compact.

What can I do now?

How to construct the compact set $K$?

Any hints about how I should proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What needs to be proved is:  Every $x\in\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$ has a neighborhood $U$ with compact closure.

Comment: @Aweygan what is the definition that you are considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=\{\alpha: X_{\alpha}~\text{is compact}\}$, given $x\in\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha}X_{\alpha}$, then for each $\alpha\in I^{c}$, look up a compact $K_{\alpha}$ such that $x_{\alpha}\in\text{int}(K_{\alpha})$, then $\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I^{c}}{K_{\alpha}}\times\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ is a compact neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.  What's the idea? Is this $\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I^{c}}{K_{\alpha}}\times\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ going to be the compact set $K$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is compact by Tikhonov's Theorem: Product of compact sets is still compact.

Comment: If $\alpha\in I^c,$ then $K_\alpha\subset X_\alpha:x_\alpha\in int(K_\alpha)$ where $X_\alpha$ is only locally compact. Why this implies $\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I^{c}}{K_{\alpha}}\times\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ is a compact nbhd of $x $?

Comment: The point is, $K_{\alpha}$ is compact by construction for those $\alpha$. For the neighbourhood, because $\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I^{c}}\text{int}(K_{\alpha})\times\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}\subseteq\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I^{c}}K_{\alpha}\times\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ and that $\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I^{c}}\text{int}(K_{\alpha})\times\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ is open.

Comment: $K_\alpha$ is compact by construction ? Isn't by hypothesis (there exists compacts for every $X_\alpha$ because each $X_\alpha$ are locally compact)?

Comment: I mean, for those $\alpha$ such that $X_{\alpha}$ is locally compact, and that locally compact means for every $x_{\alpha}\in X_{\alpha}$, one can find a compact set $K_{\alpha}$ such that the open set $\text{\int}(K_{\alpha})$ contains $x_{\alpha}$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I^{c}}\text{int}(K_{\alpha})\times\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ has the form of a basic element, Is that why is open?

Comment: Note that $I^{c}$ is a finite set, this is the assumption. So it has the form of basic open set in product topology.

Comment: and $x\in\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I^{c}}\text{int}(K_{\alpha})\times\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$  because $x_{\alpha}\in\text{int}(K_{\alpha}),\forall \alpha\in I^c$  ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: alright so now to see that this $\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I^{c}}{K_{\alpha}}\times\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ is compact, I have the proof of Tychonoff theorem, so $\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ is compact. For the finite case $\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I^{c}}{K_{\alpha}}$ the same proof can be used right?

Comment: and then this $\displaystyle\prod_{\alpha\in I^{c}}{K_{\alpha}}$ can be seen as a single compact let's say $X$ and $\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}=Y$. And the again by Tychonoff theorem, $X\times Y$ is compact, right?

Comment: Okay, your reasoning goes through.

Comment: Why my reasoning goes through, Is there a better way ?

Comment: You have explained in a good way. A more convenient way is that for each $\alpha$, no matter $\alpha\in I$ or $\in I^{c}$, the former is $X_{\alpha}$, the latter is $K_{\alpha}$, in either case it is compact, then Tichonov directly applies.

Comment: of course it's better :) .Thank you so much for your help.